# How to make a condition that evaluates according to a number in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement, conditional-statements

I want to perform a function that evaluates depending on the amount that is being requested. I will make an example in the context that I need it:

A user had to complete 20 hours of work in the week, if he fulfilled those 20 hours the result will be something like ["start"] but if he did not do it the list will be empty []

But if a user is more than 26 hours old then her list will be something like ["start", "start"]

And if it's past 30 hours then your list will look something like ["start", "start", "start"]

So the variable that I have is hourTracked that symbolizes the hours that the user should meet. I have a condition something like the following:

```
if (user_week) {
return hourtracked === 20 ? ["start"] : hourtracked >= 28 && hourtracked < 30 ? ["start", "start"] : hourtracked > 30 ? ["start", "start", "start"] : [];
}
```

but it doesn't seem to be working as it should, maybe the logic is not correct, how should I do it?

Comment: Add parentheses `( )` around your ternary-operator (`? :`)'s  conditions to make it easier to see.

Comment: Also, what does your debugger tell you?

Comment: the code will always return `[]` if `hourtracked is < 28` unless `hourstracked === 20` - you have no condition for 26, so ... not sure why you'd expect that code to just *know what you want* - it does what you wrote. Multiple nested ternary operator is not the easiest thing to read anyway - use if statements instead - also if hourtracked is `30` it will return `[]`

Comment: seems you want something more like `return hourtracked < 20 ? [] : hourtracked < 26 ? ["start"] : hourtracked <= 30 ? ["start", "start"] : ["start", "start", "start"];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you want cut-offs at <20, <26 and <=30

i.e (assuming integer values)

- 0 to 19 ... result `[]`
- 20 to 25 ... result `["start"]`
- 26 to 30 ... result `["start", "start"]`
- 31+ ... result `["start", "start", "start"]`

So

```
return hourtracked < 20 ? [] : hourtracked < 26 ? ["start"] : hourtracked <= 30 ? ["start", "start"] : ["start", "start", "start"];
```

To be honest, it's more readable to write it like

```
if (hourtracked < 20) {
    return [];
}
if (hourtracked < 26) {
    return ["start"];
}
if (hourtracked <= 30) {
    return ["start", "start"];
}
return ["start", "start", "start"];
```

Comment: That is all! Thank you very much for all your help! I was a bit confused on the correct range that I had to use. Also, I used ternary operators because I have more than one condition with this same logic but in different range values and I read on a blog that it's a good practice when you have a lot of statements right? [link](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-ternary-operator/#:~:text=It's%20a%20good%20practice%20to,avoid%20using%20the%20ternary%20operators.)